# How to convert a Text object from a parsetree output of module Pattern in python?

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-pattern

I have a list of words like this:

```
['Urgente', 'Recibimos', 'Info']
```

I used the parsetree `(parsetree(x, lemmata = True)` function to convert the words and the output for each Word is this:

```
[[Sentence('urgente/JJ/B-ADJP/O/urgente')],
[Sentence('recibimos/NN/B-NP/O/recibimos')],
[Sentence('info/NN/B-NP/O/info')]]
```

Each component of the list has the type `pattern.text.tree.Text`.

I need to obtain only the group of words into the parenthesis but I don´t know how to do this, I need this output:

```
[urgente/JJ/B-ADJP/O/urgente,
recibimos/NN/B-NP/O/recibimos,
info/NN/B-NP/O/info]
```

I use `str` to convert to string each component to the list but this changes all output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From their [documentation](https://www.clips.uantwerpen.be/pages/pattern-en#tree), there doesn't seem to be a direct method or property to get what you want.

But I found that a `Sentence` object can be printed as `Sentence('urgente/JJ/B-ADJP/O/urgente')` using `repr`. So I looked at [the source code for the `__repr__` implementation](https://github.com/clips/pattern/blob/master/pattern/text/tree.py#L1122) to see how it is formed:

```py
def __repr__(self):
    return "Sentence(%s)" % repr(" ".join(["/".join(word.tags) for word in self.words]))
```

It seems that the string "in parenthesis" is a combination of words and tags. You can then reuse that code, knowing that if you already have `pattern.text.tree.Text` objects, "*a Text is a list of Sentence objects. Each Sentence is a list of Word objects.*" (from the [Parse trees documentation](https://www.clips.uantwerpen.be/pages/pattern-en#tree)).

So here's my hacky solution:

```
parsed = list()
for data in ['Urgente', 'Recibimos', 'Info']:
    parsed.append(parsetree(data, lemmata=True))

output = list()
for text in parsed:
    for sentence in text:
        formatted = " ".join(["/".join(word.tags) for word in sentence.words])
        output.append(str(formatted))

print(output)
```

Printing `output` gives:

```
['Urgente/NNP/B-NP/O/urgente', 'Recibimos/NNP/B-NP/O/recibimos', 'Info/NNP/B-NP/O/info']
```

Note that this solution results in a list of `str`s (losing all the properties/methods from the original `parsetree` output).

Comment: Thank you. What is the function of word.tags?

Comment: @DanielMendoza From the [docstring for `Word.tags`](https://github.com/clips/pattern/blob/master/pattern/text/tree.py#L204): "_Yields a list of all the token tags as they appeared when the word was parsed. For example: ["was", "VBD", "B-VP", "O", "VP-1", "A1", "be"]_". More information on parser tags can be found in the [Parser tags documentation](https://www.clips.uantwerpen.be/pages/pattern-en#parser), such as "_NN (noun), VB (verb), JJ (adjective), RB (adverb) and IN (preposition)_".